# System diagnosis in expert system "Inference engine"

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, inference-engine

I have graduation project and I am working in an expert system"System diagnosis for diseases"(I did not begin implementation stage yet )
in expert system I did not see any useful tutorial(code) that is helping me in build a rules

I was try [openrules](http://openrules.com/index.htm) and I am not sure if it is good for expert system or not

my question is what is a good Inference engine (open source) in Java that I can build a rules and test correctly 
I see application it is name [XperRule](http://www.xpertrule.com/) but it is not free 
 if you have any information tell me because I relay need to find any way to build this system 
,my supervisor will reject my work if I did not find a right way.

thank you for reading

Comment: How far did you get now? Please share.

Comment: Hi I found Jess is good choice to develop an expert system but in simple way .. I mean it needs to more time to understand more concept of CLPS language as basic then you will understand Jess very well.I hope that helpful.